# On a get request, how can I start program, and then using another get request stop it?

Tags: javascript, java, html, http, routes

I'm running a website using java and tomcat. At a high level what I'm trying to do is route a start button to a java method which makes an endless amount of calls to some other resource. When I want to stop that program I would push the stop button.

I have figured out the start part, but cannot stop it because I don't think the state of the get request page gets saved. I have a few global variables in that class which I think keep getting reset everytime I make a get request. How could I prevent that from happening?

```
@Path("/myresource")
public class MyResource {
continuousMethod sample = new continuousMethod()
boolean collecting = false;
/**
 * Method handling HTTP GET requests. The returned object will be sent
 * to the client as "text/plain" media type.
 *
 * @return String that will be returned as a text/plain response.
 */
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Path("/collect")
public String startCollection() throws URISyntaxException {
    System.out.println("Made it here");
    sample.start();
    collecting = true;
    return "Collecting";
}
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Path("/stopcollect")
public String stopCollection() {

    sample.close();
    collecting = false;
    return "Finished collecting!";

    //return "Not collecting";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of `sessions` instead of global variables.

Comment: Thanks for the input, directed me to understand what I was trying to do better.